# Updating 'username' field logs user out (flask-login - MongoDB) - Class issue?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-login

I’m working on my flask app (using flask-login and PyMongo) and have this class for my user, and this loader (this is the full users.py file):

```
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from app import login, mongo

class User():
    def __init__(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, _id, is_admin):
        self.username = username
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self._id = _id
        self.is_admin = is_admin

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username

    @staticmethod
    def check_password(password_hash, password):
        return check_password_hash(password_hash, password)


@login.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    user = mongo.db.users.find_one({'username': username})
    if not user:
        return None
    return User(user['username'], user['first_name'], user['last_name'], user['email'], user['_id'], user['is_admin'])
```

Register, login and logout routes work fine, but I have a problem with my update_account route, which updates the user information.
I can update all the fields in my database, but when I update `‘username’` I get logged out , or rather logged out and redirected to `/login?next=%2Faccount HTTP` (albeit the field gets correctly updated).
I’m aware there’s something wrong in my class, so I tried to modify the end of it and the loader by using the `_id`, such as:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, _id, is_admin):
        self.username = username
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self._id = _id
        self.is_admin = is_admin


    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self._id

@login.user_loader
def load_user(_id):
    user = mongo.db.users.find_one({'_id': _id})
    if not user:
        return None
    return User(user['username'], user['first_name'], user['last_name'], user['email'], user['_id'] , user['is_admin'])
```

But then I get a `TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable`.

Extra information: When I update any of the other fields I correctly get in my console:

```
127.0.0.1 - -"POST /account HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - -"GET /account HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But updating the username provokes:

```
127.0.0.1 - -"POST /account HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - -"GET /account HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - -"GET /login?next=%2Faccount HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

In case it helps, this is my route to edit the account:

```
@app.route('/account', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    updated_user = {'username': form.username.data, 'first_name': form.first_name.data,
                    'last_name': form.last_name.data, 'email': form.email.data}
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        mongo.db.users.update_one(
            {'_id': current_user._id}, {"$set": updated_user})
        flash('Updated!', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('account'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.first_name.data = current_user.first_name
        form.last_name.data = current_user.last_name
        form.email.data = current_user.email
    return render_template('account.html', title="About", form=form)
```

Could any of you help me sort this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by logging the user in immediately when I update it, within the same route. So a bit of a backend trick but unnoticeable to the user.

Comment: Hi Guillermo, I am also looking at some flask-login MongoDB working snippet, I was hoping you could share how it works. Any repo?

Answer (score 2):

The `_id` field is represented in pymongo as ObjectId instance (from the `bson` library).

Either remove this field from the offending function, or convert it to a string first.

Comment: I tried to convert it to a string but I didn't manage. What way would you suggest? Also, would it be possible to remove it from my function? I think I will need it. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd need to see the function.

Comment: I just updated my question, but there wasn't much more to it in my users.py. I also added the route at the end of the question just in case it helps.

Comment: If you want I can share my repository with you, and the live deployment so you see what is the problem.